# Unable to run IntelliJ project with MySQL and Gradle under WildFly

Tags: mysql, gradle, intellij-idea, wildfly

```
14:10:16,119 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "Countries-Balci-1.0.war")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.app.\"Countries-Balci-1.0\".jdbc.CountriesDB"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.persistenceunit.\"Countries-Balci-1.0.war#Countries-BalciPU\" is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.app.\"Countries-Balci-1.0\".jdbc.CountriesDB]",
        "jboss.persistenceunit.\"Countries-Balci-1.0.war#Countries-BalciPU\".__FIRST_PHASE__ is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.app.\"Countries-Balci-1.0\".jdbc.CountriesDB]"
    ]
}
14:10:16,120 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "Countries-Balci-1.0.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.app.\"Countries-Balci-1.0\".jdbc.CountriesDB"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.persistenceunit.\"Countries-Balci-1.0.war#Countries-BalciPU\" is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.app.\"Countries-Balci-1.0\".jdbc.CountriesDB]",
        "jboss.persistenceunit.\"Countries-Balci-1.0.war#Countries-BalciPU\".__FIRST_PHASE__ is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.app.\"Countries-Balci-1.0\".jdbc.CountriesDB]"
    ]
}
```

I am attaching the screenshot of the project displaying some files.

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

[image: IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Project Files]

Comment: The datasource JNDI name doesn't exists which creates the failure.

Comment: The datasource JNDI name doesn't exist where? Can you be specific? Many thanks!

Comment: I have the JNDI name specified in WildFly standalone.xml as <datasource jndi-name="java:/CountriesDB" pool-name="CountriesDB">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**java:app/jdbc/CountriesDB** is the name you are using in your persistence unit while you have registered the datasource under the name **java:/CountriesDB**. As you can see they don't match.